# split a field with awk, then use second part of split to add to new field when printing

Tags: linux, bash, awk, split

I have a file that has the following structure (tab delimited):

```
Geneid  Chr Start   End Strand  Length  WI_D_9_18_21_A_contigs_sorted.bam
1_1 c_1246  1   1395    +   1395    1028
1_2 c_1246  1407    2168    +   762 821
1_3 c_1246  2198    2971    +   774 874
1_4 c_1246  2986    3969    +   984 938
1_5 c_1246  4163    5047    +   885 874
1_6 c_1246  5085    5333    +   249 362
1_7 c_1246  5549    5878    +   330 493
1_8 c_1246  6057    6713    +   657 696
```

I am trying to create a new file (tab delimited) that includes fields $1, $2, $6, $7. I also want to add on the second half of Geneid (1, 2, 3, etc) to the end of the elements in the second field (Chr) after a "_"

**This is what I would like the file to look like after (see field $2 aka Chr column):**

```
Geneid  Chr Length  WI_D_9_18_21_A_contigs_sorted.bam
1_1 c_1246_1    1395    1028
1_2 c_1246_2    762 821
1_3 c_1246_3    774 874
1_4 c_1246_4    984 938
1_5 c_1246_5    885 874
1_6 c_1246_6    249 362
1_7 c_1246_7    330 493
1_8 c_1246_8    657 696
1_9 c_1246_9    663 725
```

Each column is separated by a tab.

I have tried the following code, and I cannot get the second part of the split $1 to be added to $2 after a "_".

```
awk -F '\t' '{OFS = FS} FNR<=1{next} NR>2 {split($1,a,_); $2 = $2 "_" a[$2];} 1 {print $1,$2,$6,$7}' WI_D_9_18_21_A_bin.6_fC_gene_coverage.tsv > test.txt

awk -F '\t' '{OFS = FS} FNR<=1{next} {n[$1,$2]=split($1,a,"_");} NR>1 {print $1,$2 "_" n[$2],$6,$7}' WI_D_9_18_21_A_bin.6_fC_gene_coverage.tsv > test.txt

awk -F '\t' '{OFS = FS} FNR<=1{next} {split($1,a,"_");next} FNR>1 {print $1,$2 "_" a[$2],$6,$7}' WI_D_9_18_21_A_bin.6_fC_gene_coverage.tsv > test.txt
```

So far, this is all I can get:

```
Geneid  Chr Length  WI_D_9_18_21_A_contigs_sorted.bam
1_1 c_1246_ 1395    1028
1_2 c_1246_ 762 821
1_3 c_1246_ 774 874
1_4 c_1246_ 984 938
1_5 c_1246_ 885 874
1_6 c_1246_ 249 362
1_7 c_1246_ 330 493
1_8 c_1246_ 657 696
1_9 c_1246_ 663 725
```

I know I am doing something wrong and cannot figure it out. I just want these numbers in the second part of Geneid to be added after the numbers in the Chr column (c_1246 --> c_1246_1, etc). All help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you want the output to be tab separated?

Comment: I do want the output to be tab separated, thank you for asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your third attempt is not far from it but there are several issues:

1. To access the second entry in array `a` use `a[2]`, not `a[$2]`
2. With `FNR>=1 {next}` you completely skip the header line (`next` stops the processing of the current record and restarts with the next record)
3. With `{split($1,a,"_");next}` you skip all other lines (no output)

Here is a minimal modification of your own code that should work with any POSIX `awk` (but see below for some improvements and a different approach):

```
awk -F '\t' '{OFS = FS} FNR<=1{print $1,$2,$6,$7; next}
  {split($1,a,"_")} FNR>1 {print $1,$2 "_" a[2],$6,$7}' WI_D_9_18_21_A_bin.6_fC_gene_coverage.tsv > test.txt
```

There are also some inefficiencies:

1. Executing `{OFS = FS}` on each record is useless, doing this only once in the `BEGIN` block, or adding the `-v OFS='\t'` option is enough.
2. After the first `next` we know that the current line is not the header, no need to test (`FNR>1`).
3. The two last blocks can be merged.

Which leads to:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'NR==1 {print $1,$2,$6,$7; next}
  {split($1,a,"_"); print $1,$2 "_" a[2],$6,$7}' WI_D_9_18_21_A_bin.6_fC_gene_coverage.tsv > test.txt
```

We could further simply by factorizing the print statement:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'NR>1 {split($1,a,"_"); $2=$2 "_" a[2]}
  {print $1,$2,$6,$7}' WI_D_9_18_21_A_bin.6_fC_gene_coverage.tsv > test.txt
```

Now for a slightly different approach: `awk` allows to change the input field separator during operations. So, you can start with just tab for the header line and continue with tab and underscore.

Example, that should work with any POSIX `awk`:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'NR==1 {print $1,$2,$6,$7; FS="[\t_]"; next}
  {print $1 "_" $2,$3 "_" $4 "_" $2,$8,$9}' WI_D_9_18_21_A_bin.6_fC_gene_coverage.tsv > test.txt
```

In this case the code is not simpler and not especially easier to understand but in other circumstances this other approach could be useful.

Comment: @EdMorton : they aren't entirely identical :  `echo 'apple.bee 23623.9291' | gawk -p- -be '{ print split($_, __, "."), split($_, __, /./) }'` prints `3 21`. Those 2 numbers would match if they were identical to `split()`. `nawk`s and `mawk`s also behave the same way, as does every `gawk` special flag I tried. Neither does single space match either `echo 'apple.bee   236 23.929    1' | [mgn]awk '{ print split($+_, __, " "), split($+_, __, / /) }'` ::: `4 9` (string version does it like default `FS` way, but `/ /` does it one space at a time, so run of spaces mean empty cells in between.

Comment: @EdMorton : i'm guessing the `POSIX` spec is being interpreted as - `if it's actually a single character represented by a variable or double-quoted string (or basically any expression that evaluates to length(str) == 1) instead of regex form, then invoke the special rule(s)`

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU AWK

FS and OFS can be changed to tab

```
$ awk '{print $1,(NR==1 ? $2 : $2 gensub(/^[^_]*/,"",1,$1)),$6,$7}' file
Geneid Chr Length WI_D_9_18_21_A_contigs_sorted.bam
1_1 c_1246_1 1395 1028
1_2 c_1246_2 762 821
1_3 c_1246_3 774 874
1_4 c_1246_4 984 938
1_5 c_1246_5 885 874
1_6 c_1246_6 249 362
1_7 c_1246_7 330 493
1_8 c_1246_8 657 696
```

Or with any AWK as @RenaudPacalet mentioned

```
awk '{t=$1; sub(/.*_/,"",t); print $1, $2 ((NR==1) ? "" : "_" t), $6, $7}' file
```

Comment: `gensub` is a GNU `awk` extension, you should maybe add this information for those who use other `awk`. According the code provided by the OP, `FS` and `OFS` shall be set to tab, not space or the default.

Comment: Note that `{t=$1; sub(/.*_/,"",t); print $1, $2 ((NR==1) ? "" : "_" t), $6, $7}` should work with any POSIX `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```bash
$ awk -v OFS=" " 'NR==1{print $1, $2, $6, $7;next}{split($1,a,"_");print $1,$2"_"a[2],$6,$7}' file
Geneid Chr Length WI_D_9_18_21_A_contigs_sorted.bam
1_1 c_1246_1 1395 1028
1_2 c_1246_2 762 821
1_3 c_1246_3 774 874
1_4 c_1246_4 984 938
1_5 c_1246_5 885 874
1_6 c_1246_6 249 362
1_7 c_1246_7 330 493
1_8 c_1246_8 657 696
```

print the desired header columns (`NR==1{print $1, $2, $6, $7;next}` , thanks @Marius_Couet) then split the first field (`split($1,a,"_")`) and append the second entry of the resulting array to the second field.

Comment: According the code provided by the OP, `FS` and `OFS` shall be set to tab, not space or the default.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet right.. but the desired output shown by OP doesn't show the tab

Comment: Tabs are not rendered properly by the markdown rendering engine. This is why it is always better to replace tabs with spaces in questions and answers.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet if you look at the question in edit mode, you'll see that there is no markdown attempt by the OP

Comment: At least they indented the code blocks by 4 spaces. Anyway, even plain text is markdown. If you want it to be rendered correctly better avoid tabs.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I wasn't sure how to improve how the output looked - but yes everything should be tab delimited

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
    NR>1 { sfx=$1; sub(/[^_]+/,"",sfx) }
    { print $1, $2 sfx, $6, $7 }
' file
Geneid  Chr     Length  WI_D_9_18_21_A_contigs_sorted.bam
1_1     c_1246_1        1395    1028
1_2     c_1246_2        762     821
1_3     c_1246_3        774     874
1_4     c_1246_4        984     938
1_5     c_1246_5        885     874
1_6     c_1246_6        249     362
1_7     c_1246_7        330     493
1_8     c_1246_8        657     696
```

To compare with other possible answers, the above is:

- Not specifying the `print` statement multiple times (duplicate code is undesirable).
- Not modifying `$2` or any other field (and so not forcing awk to inefficiently recompile `$0` from it's fields for every input line).
- Not modifying `$0` (and so not forcing awk to inefficiently re-split `$0` into fields for every input line).
- Only doing `sub()` on the necessary lines (not on the first line).
- Setting `FS` to tab so it can handle a blank input field correctly.
- Setting `OFS` to tab so it produces the desired output separator.
- Setting both `FS` and `OFS` to the same value at the same time to avoid specifying `"\t"` twice (duplicate code is undesirable).

If you really wanted to use `split()` for this for some reason then just change `sfx=$1; sub(/[^_]+/,"",sfx)` to `sfx="_" a[split($1,a,"_")]` or, if you prefer a bit of extra clarity, `n=split($1,a,"_"); sfx="_" a[n]`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{split($1, a, "_"); $2 = $2 "_" a[2]; print $1, $2, $6, $7}' OFS="\t" WI_D_9_18_21_A_bin.6_fC_gene_coverage.tsv
```

Comment: According the code provided by the OP, `FS` and `OFS` shall be set to tab, not space or the default.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU cut and sed):

```
cut -f1,2,6,7 file | sed -E 's/(_\S+)\t\S+/&\1/' >outFile
```

Use cut to select only the columns needed and sed to adjust the second column with the second half of the first column.

Answer (score -1):

```
mawk '($3 = $6)^_ + NR + ($4 = $7)^_ < (NF = 4) || 
      $2 = $2 substr($1, index($1, "_"))' FS='\t' OFS='\t'
```

> or a single combo assignment :

```
gawk 'NF = ($2 = $2 (1 < NR ? substr($1, 
           index($1, "_")) : _) FS $6 FS $7)^_ + !_' FS='\t' OFS='\t'
```

---

```
Geneid  Chr     Length  WI_D_9_18_21_A_contigs_sorted.bam
1_1    c_1246_1   1395  1028
1_2    c_1246_2    762  821
1_3    c_1246_3    774  874
1_4    c_1246_4    984  938
1_5    c_1246_5    885  874
1_6    c_1246_6    249  362
1_7    c_1246_7    330  493
1_8    c_1246_8    657  696
```